# How to use ampersand in hover effect with parent element on pseudo elements?

Tags: sass

How ampersand can be used in hover effect with parent element with `::after` or `::before` pseudo element or how this could be nested to make it work?

```
.showcase::after {
    content: '';
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;        
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/gzOBup/showcase.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;        
    display: block;
    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    transition: $transAll;

    :hover {
    filter: blur(0px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    }
}
```

Comment: try &:hover. it should work

Comment: No it won't. You can't hover a pseudo element.

Comment: @QuentinVeron You're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly use the `hover` selector on a pseudo element.
In your case, you could use the `@at-root`directive to make it work.

**Demo:**

```
.showcase::after {
    content: '';
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;        
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/gzOBup/showcase.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;        
    display: block;
    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    transition: $transAll;

    @at-root .showcase:hover::after {
        filter: blur(0px);
        -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. Please look at comment below, it does work. Thank you for your help, BTW.

Comment: It works this time. I'll have to read about @at-root directive.

Comment: To be honest, you could just make 2 different declaration blocks. It's not always useful to rely on nesting.

Comment: Yes, I could. And also I could write it in css, but I want scss style.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.showcase{
    &::after {
        content: '';
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;        
        background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/gzOBup/showcase.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;        
        display: block;
        filter: blur(10px);
        -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
        transition: $transAll;   
    }

    &:hover {
        &::after {
            filter: blur(0px);
            -webkit-filter: blur(0px);       
        }
    }
}
```